# Alternative phrase/word for 'Up to this point'

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a way to rephrase the following sentence:

> ***Up to this point***, Rosemary’s ‘maternal instinct’ had remained dormant.

The phrase I'm looking to replace is: ***Up to this point***

Comment: What ideas have you had so far?

Answer (score 1):

> ***Hitherto***, Rosemary’s ‘maternal instinct’ had remained dormant.

ODO:

> **[hitherto](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/hitherto)**
>   *ADVERB*
>   Until now or until the point in time under discussion.
>
> ‘He was billeted at her home where her seven brothers had hitherto
>   protected her from any approach by potential suitors.’

Answer (score 0):

**Previously**, Rosemary’s ‘maternal instinct’ had remained dormant.

> Existing or occurring before something else in time or order; prior

[TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/previous)

Or 'until now'

Comment: @Jim ... yea sorta felt iffy ... i edited

Answer (score 0):

'Heretofore' should fit the bill

Comment: Please add a source to support your answer.

Comment: If the bill includes wanting to sound like a Dickensian lawyer.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I would opt for *so far*, *until then*, or *prior to that time*.

For more variety, I recommend you the [following list of synonyms in WorldHippo](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/up_to_this_point.html):

up to the present moment, hitherto, so far, thus far, till now, to date, as yet, until now, until today, up to now, as of now, up to the present time, yet, thitherto, till then, until then, up to then, up to the present, up to that point, heretofore, up until then, up until now, till the present, up till now, by this time, until the present, theretofore, previously, up to this time, still, formerly, already, before, earlier, even now,
before this, since, beforehand, earlier on, prior to now, prior to this time, prior to the present time, until this time, before now, by now.

Comment: Hello, loved.by.Jesus. 'Render therefore to all their dues: tribute to whom tribute is due ...' (WordHippo?)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, absolutely, for that reason I set the link to WordHippo and then colon, meaning that the list belongs to the linked site (no need to open extra tabs in the browser). I think, in my answer, attribution is unmistakable. :) Blessings! PS: by the way, you might also give attribution to your citation "Romans 13:7 King James Version" ;) (friendly teasing) PS2:Anyway, at last, I added the name explicitly. "If it is possible, as much as depends on you, live peaceably with all men." (Ro 12:18 NKJV)

Comment: If you don't _clearly_ show (not _hidden in the link_) the source of a quote, you expose yourself to prosecution for plagiarism. It's echoed in the site rules here on ELU. The AV is, I believe, out of copyright nowadays. I was aiming for a little subtlety; I assumed you'd place the reference. Sometimes we can overdo even a good thing: I remember a prophetic teacher once saying [doubtless a paraphrase by now]  'God rarely dazzles, He shows restraint. Yes, He made many glorious varieties of trees – but He didn't rivet placards on each one saying "I made this. _Worship Me!_" '